# node.js + stylus + idea: проблема символов <>

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, stylus

При создании *File Watcher* для *Stylus* файлов возникла небольшая проблема.

Хочу указать в *Arguments* выходной файл, но появляется ошибка:

```
/home/ivan/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus < main.styl > mainin.css
/home/ivan/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:640
if (err) throw err;
               ^
Error: ENOENT, stat '<'
 at Error (native)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

В поле *Arguments*: `< $FileName$ > mainin.css`

Прошу помощи!

Comment: Так а зачем вы в скобки $FileName$ оборачиваете? Странно еще, что оно на уровне баша не преобразовывается в перехват ввода/вывода.

Answer (score 1):

Название файла `main.styl` можно просто параметром передать:

```
node_modules/.bin/stylus main.styl > mainin.css
```